# Get Full Path of Files

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to upload multi file that I have form like this:

**in the View**

```
 = simple_form_for(@subcategory_image,:url => post_images_image_uploads_path(:domain_name => @domain_name), :html => { 
     %input{:multiple => "", :name => "files[]", :type => "file", :id => "files"}
     %button.btn.btn-primary.start{:type => "submit", :id => "submit"}
```

**in controller**

```
 def post_images
     files = params[:files]

 end
```

**How can I get the full path of the images or files?**

Comment: As I understand it you can't get the full path of files that the user selects for file input elements, nor should you be able to because the structure of a user's filesystem should be private. Why do you need it?

Comment: coz I want to get width and height of image.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood. Can't your server-side code do that once the files are uploaded? You can't access the client file system from JS.